# Maven Nexus Repository

Tags: java, maven, repository, nexus

I have a private Nexus repository set up for Maven on one PC in my LAN. I want to connect to the same Nexus repository from another PC in my LAN. How can I accomplish this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to setup the settings file:
http://books.sonatype.com/nexus-book/reference/config-maven.html#ex-maven-nexus-simple

Make sure to use the IP address/ name of the machine running Nexus instead of localhost.

AFAIK, this should work out-of-the-box: https://books.sonatype.com/nexus-book/reference/running.html

Comment: What if it requires a username and password to connect? Can I connect to a repository created on another computer without using Nexus?

Comment: I haven't tried. You can try the server section in the settings file, but I don't think it will work. Otherwise try to specify the username and password as part of the URL (eg. https://username:password@your-machine:8081/nexus/content/groups/public). Make sure you're using HTTPS, so you won't send passords in plain text over the network: https://books.sonatype.com/nexus-book/reference/ssl-sect-ssl-direct.html

Comment: Great to here! The one with username/password in URL or the one with the server section?

Answer (score 0):

You have to make the changes in installed `Maven/conf` and `setting.xml` file and something like below which i did for Artifactory.

```
<pluginRepositories>
        <pluginRepository>
          <snapshots>
            <enabled>false</enabled>
          </snapshots>
          <id>central</id>
          <name>remote-repos</name>
          <url>http://localhost:8081/artifactory/remote-repos</url>
        </pluginRepository>
        <pluginRepository>
          <snapshots />
          <id>snapshots</id>
          <name>remote-repos</name>
          <url>http://localhost:8081/artifactory/remote-repos</url>
        </pluginRepository>
      </pluginRepositories>
```

FYI please check https://support.sonatype.com/entries/20943003-Configure-Maven-to-Download-from-Nexus

Comment: Can you please tell me what changes to make ?